# How to test nested dependencies with angular-spectator

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I have an angular component that is using a service(service1) that is dependent on another service (service2).

How do I test this? I would like to mock both services.

```js
export class service2 {
    public someFunction() {}

    constructor() {}
}


export class service1 {
    public somOtherFunction() {}
    constructor(s: Service2) {
         this.s.someFunction();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'component',
    providers: [Service1],

 })
 export class component {
    constructor(private service:Service1) {
        this.service.someOtherFunction();
    }
 }
```

My testbed is looking like this.

```js
describe('component', () => { 
    let component: Spectator<component>;
    const createComponent = createComponentFactory();

    beforeEach(() => component = createComponent());

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

Pretty standard but I am unable to figure out how to mock the services.
Can anyone help ??

Comment: Are you using Jasmine and Karma?

Comment: Service1 is provided by the component itself, is Service2 provided application wide via a NgModule?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Depending on whether we provide a Service on component or module level, we can override and essentially mock them either via `componentProviders: []` or `providers:[]`

Try the following:

```js
class MockedService1 {

  someOtherFunction() {
    return 'Some stubbed values';
  }
}

const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: YourComponentUnderTest,
  componentProviders: [
    { provide: Service1, useClass: MockedService1 },
    // { provide: Service2, useClass: Service2 }
  ],
  imports: []
});
```

If the dependency hierarchy is `Component -> Service1 -> Service2`, when we mock Service1 we shouldn't have to mock Service2.

Comment: a jez, just saw that the service is provided by the component. don't know if above works then. but you could give it a quick try

Comment: No, it does not work. Complaining Complains about Service2.

Comment: @lg.lindstrom updated the answer. Plz take a look if it fits your needs

Comment: I seems to function but I wanted to avoid those manually mock every service. A lot of work. The idea with a framework is to avoid extra work,, or :)

Comment: Did not get it working with the built in Jasmine spies of spectator.  Of course you don't need to create the whole class everytime.  `{provide: Service1, useValue: { someOtherFunction: () => 'No cats allowed!'}}` will work as well. It's a one liner. So in my opinion the same as if you would mock the value via the spectator component.

Comment: Your latest example will not work because the constructor of Service2 contains reference to another service. Only reason MockedService1 in your example worked is that there is no reference to another service there.

Comment: I'm sure it will. Thats the whole point of mocking / stubbing dependencies. When I mock `Service1` I don't have to care about the dependencies of the "real" Service1.

It does not make sense to mock a service in service that's already mocked. That would be a sign that you try to test too much at once.